# citus can I use join if I use citus?

Tags: database, citus

citus can I use join if I use citus ?

And yes are they performant ?

.....................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> citus can I use join if I use citus ?

Yes, you can use joins with Citus.
https://docs.citusdata.com/en/v10.0/develop/reference_sql.html#joins.

Most of the joins between different Citus table types are just supported, but some of them requires enabling repartition joins.
https://docs.citusdata.com/en/v10.0/develop/api_guc.html?highlight=enable_repartition_joins#citus-enable-repartition-joins-boolean

As of Citus 10, joins between local tables and distributed tables are also supported.
https://docs.citusdata.com/en/v10.0/develop/api_guc.html?highlight=enable_repartition_joins#citus-local-table-join-policy-enum

> And yes are they performant ?

Citus joins tables very efficiently when tables are co-located.
https://docs.citusdata.com/en/v10.0/develop/reference_sql.html#co-located-joins

Comment: thanks for your help. Is the performance in read good if I use joins ?

Comment: Yes when the tables are co-located. For the other join types, there will be some performance drop since there would be some extra network roundtrip between the worker nodes.
For instance: for repartition joins, data needs to be re-shuffled across the worker nodes and that wouldn't be as performant as co-located joins.